# How to filter a List using sql like url parameters in Java?

Tags: java

How to filter a list/collection of streams based on url parameters, for example:

```
?filter=(type=="audio"&&systemBitrate<100000)||(type=="video"&&systemBitrate<1024000)
```

I know this can be done using statically:

```
List<StreamItem> results = streamList.stream().filter(s -> s.type == "audio" && s.systemBitrate < 100000).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Simple object:

```
public class StreamItem {
    String name;
    String type;
    int systemBitrate;
}
```

The idea is to dynamically filter playback manifest in a similar way to the one below and play only selected tracks:

```
curl -v 'http://demo.unified-streaming.com/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/Manifest?filter=(type=="audio"%26%26systemBitrate<100000)||(type=="video"%26%26systemBitrate<1024000)'
```

Comment: You could define a method that created a `Predicate<StreamItem>` based on your inputs and pass it to the filter method. Like `myCustomPreducate = createPricateFor(input1, input2, ..., inputN)` and then do `stream.filter(myCustomPredicate)`.

Comment: Do not compare strings with `==` as you are doing in `s.type == "audio"`. Use `equals` instead. See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use one of the "Expression Language" libraries,
to compile your filter expression and then apply it to the elements of your stream.

Below is a short example using [MVEL](https://github.com/mvel/mvel):

*pom.xml*

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
     <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

*java code*

```
Serializable expr = MVEL.compileExpression(
   "(type==\"audio\"&&systemBitrate<100000)||(type==\"video\"&&systemBitrate<1024000)"
);

Arrays.asList(
    new StreamItem("audio",10000),
    new StreamItem("audio",200000),
    new StreamItem("video",200000),
    new StreamItem("video",2000000)
)
.stream()
.filter(e->MVEL.executeExpression(expr,e,boolean.class))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*output*

```
 Element{type='audio', systemBitrate=10000}
 Element{type='video', systemBitrate=200000}
```

Please note that your StreamItem class must have getters defined for both *type* and *systemBitrate* properties, for the MVEL to be able to resolve them.

Don't expect this to be blazing fast, yet it still should be fast enough for most practical tasks, taking that expression is compiled, before use.

Filtering a list of 1000000 (one million) StreamItems, using the expression above, takes ~150ms on my laptop, on average.